# SQL Server cascade does not delete the child of a parent where the parent is also a child of another parent

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, cascade

Microsoft SQL Server 2012 & ASP.NET

I need some help with the following that I am struggling with, I have 3 tables in the database:

```
NumberOne > NumberTwo > NumberThree
```

**NumberOne:**

- id (int)

**NumberTwo:**

- id (int)
- numberone_id

**NumberThree**

- id (int)
- numbertwo_id

I have a foreign key from `id` (number one) to `numberone_id` (number two) and a foreign key from `id` (number two) to `numbertwo_id` (number three). These keys have `Cascade` as their `Delete` rule. Now, when I programmatically delete the number one table, number two and number three are also deleted. But when I programmatically delete number two table, and I want to keep table one, number three should be deleted but it doesn't.

Why is this and how can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

As requested:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[REACTIONFILES](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [reactions_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [reactionsFile] [varbinary](max) NOT NULL,
    [reactionsName] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_REACTIONFILES] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[REACTIONS](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [tickets_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [contents] [varchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [users_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [reactionStartdate] [date] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_REACTIONS] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TICKETS](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [subject] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [categories_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [priorities_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [statuses_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [users_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [usergroups_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [isPublic] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [devStartdate] [date] NULL,
    [devEnddate] [date] NULL,
    [devTime] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [commentIntern] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [commentExtern] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [releaseVersion] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [ticketStartdate] [date] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TICKETS] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: What happens if you delete numberTwo? Show your create statement for table numberTwo

Comment: If I delete numberTwo, numberOne is still there (as supposed), numberTwo is deleted (as supposed) and numberThree is still there (should be deleted).

Comment: Can you **show us** the T-SQL code to set up those tables and their FK relationships?

Comment: How do I do that, I don't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: If the table and FK relationships are set up **correctly**, this works just fine. Tested with SQL Server 2012 - see @Damien_the_unbeliever 's answer - this work. So your setup must be fishy - something's not set up correctly. **HOW** did you create those tables and relationships? You should be able to script out a T-SQL script showing how those tables and their FK relationship has been defined (Object Explorer > Tasks > Generate Scripts)

Answer (score 2):

I'm unable to reproduce this. Here's a script (and the reason I've placed this in an answer even though it's a comment).

Can you please create a script that demonstrates the problem?

```
create table one(id int not null primary key)
go
insert into one(id) values (1),(2),(3)
go
create table two(id int not null primary key, one_id int not null references one(id) on delete cascade)
go
insert into two(id,one_id) values (1,1),(2,2),(3,3)
go
create table three(id int not null primary key, two_id int not null references two(id) on delete cascade)
go
insert into three(id,two_id) values (1,1),(2,2),(3,3)
go
delete from one where id = 3
delete from two where id = 2
select * from two
select * from three
select * from one
```

Results:

```
id          one_id
----------- -----------
1           1

(1 row(s) affected)

id          two_id
----------- -----------
1           1

(1 row(s) affected)

id
-----------
1
2

(2 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: +1 correct - if the tables and the FK relationships are set up **correctly**, then this *just works like a charm*